Theorem 5.2.1 of Systolic Geometry and Topology
Picture below is from Katz's Systolic Geometry and Topology, where $sys \pi_1(\mathcal G)=\inf\limits_\beta length (\beta)$, $\beta$ is the noncontractible loop of $(\sum,\mathcal G)$. I want to know how to prove Theorem 5.2.1 from the Gromov's inequality (5.2.3) ? However, seemly, it is not straightforward.
What I try:  In fact, I may be on the wrong track since I suspected it was wrong.
Consider the standard real projective plane $(\mathbb R \mathbb P^2, \mathcal G)$,  $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ is the quotient of the round sphere $S^2$ by the antipodal map, $\mathcal G$ is the quotient metric which is   constant curvature metric. Then
$$
sys \pi_1( \mathcal G) = \pi,  ~~~ area(B) =2\pi = area( \mathcal G)
$$
Now, (5.2.2) is optimal. But (5.2.3) is $\pi^2\le \frac{8}{3}\pi$ which is wrong.



